# Prove that $\displaystyle \lim_{k→\infty} \|f−f∗g_k\|_1=0$

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $(g_i)$ be  a sequence of functions such that $g_k: \mathbb{R}^n \to [0,\infty)$, $\text{supp}\, (g_k) \subset \overline B(0, 1/k)$ and $\int g_k (x) \, dx =1$ for all $k=1, 2, 3, \ldots$. Let  $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Show that
$$
\lim_{k \to \infty} \|f - f*g_k\|_1 =0.
$$

What I have tried:

We have the following lemma: Let $1≤p≤∞$, $f∈L_1$, $g\in L_p$. Then $f∗g\in L_p$ and $\|f∗g\|_{L_p}≤\|f\|_{L_1}\|g\|_{L_p}$. Because $f\in L_1$ and $g_k\in L_1\; \forall \,k$ we can calculate:
$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \|f - f*g_k\|_1 =\lim_{k \to \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x) -\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(y)g_k(x-y)\,dy\,dx $$
$$\leq \lim_{k \to \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x)-\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(y)\,dy\int_{\overline B(0, 1/k)}g_k(x-y)\,dy\,dx$$
$$=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x)\,dx-\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(y)\,dy=0$$
Does this make any sense or is it in the right direction? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is in the right direction but a little too cavalier. One thing is that you lost absolute value at the beginning  i.e. $||h||_{1} =  \int |h| dx$, the second is that you use Fubini's theorem about changing order of integrals without pointing it out. Lastly, I do not like how you write it down i.e. I see limit with $k \to \infty$ on the left and inside the expression  ball with radious $\frac{1}{k}$. It is sort of confusing. In my opinion it would look better if you said something like - "if $k$ is large then .... <br/> But the idea is good.

Comment: @Salcio I am afraid you are misleading OP. The very first step in expanding $\|f-f*g_k|
|$ is wrong, so the entire thing breaks down. It cannot be fixed easily.  So how can the attempt be in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

The norm of $f$ in $L^{1}$ is not $\int f(x)dx $. It is $\int |f(x)|dx$ and absolute value is absolutely essential!.

First consider the case when $f$ is continuous with compact support. $\|f-f*g_k\|_1=\int \int |f(x)-\int f(x-y)g_k(y) dy|dx \leq \int \int |f(x)-f(x-y)|g_k(y) dydx $. The inside integral can be taken over $\|y\| <\frac  1k$. Also, the integral w.r.t. $x$ can be taken from $-T-1$ to $T+1$ if $f$ has upport in $[-T,T]$.  Using uniform continuity of $f$ we see easily that $\|f-f*g_k\|_1 <\epsilon$ provided $k$ is sufficiently large.

For the general case you have to use the fact that $f$ can be approximated in $L^{1}$ norm by continuous functions with compact support. You will also need the inequality $\|f_1*f_2\|_1 \leq \|f_1\|_1 \|f_2\|_1$. This part of the proof is fairly straightforward and I will leave the details to you.